# Is their a method calling a function wheether a variable changes value, without using Object Orientated Programming?

Tags: python

Is it possible to trigger a function whenever a variable changes value, without using OOP (using Procedural) In python 3.6?

Their is no code for this question as I am just asking a generic question.

Comment: So why tag this Python? Everything is an object here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. This is off-topic (it's far too broad): "Their is no code for this question as I am just asking a generic question."

Comment: Cause python is the language I hope to use. I will add this to the question

Comment: Write a setter function? `def set_x(value): x = value; callback_function()`?

Comment: Please be clearer, do you mean if a *name* changes to refer to a different object, or if the object itself changes?  Note that some python objects cannot change, they are immutable.  For example, `x = [1,2,3,4]` then `x[0] = 42` means that the object referred to by `x` changes, `x` still refers to the same object, but `x[0]` does not.  `y = x` mean that both `y` and `x` refer to the same list object.

Comment: Read about [8.6. Function definitions::decorators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function)

Comment: variables are just names for object in memory and OOP is everywhere even you go functional in Python. If you use `@property` or you can create your own custom descriptor.

Comment: In case you need to debug your program, I recommend to log changes manually (either using `logging` module or just `print`) or to use debugging tools like `pdb` or `ipdb`.